# Alter datatype of complex type(array<struct>>) in hive

Tags: hive, ddl

I have a field of type :

```
col1:  array<struct<a:string.b:array<string>>>
```

I want to alter the datatype to

```
col1:   array<struct<a:string.b:array<string>,c:struct<c1:<struct>,c2:<struct>>>>
```

I am using the following command:

```
alter table tablename change columnn col1 col1 array<struct<a:string.b:array<string>,c:struct<c1:<struct>,c2:<struct>>>>
```

This seems to giving me following error:

SQL Error [1] [08S01]: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error: type expected at the position 0 of '::::array<struct<a:string.b:array,c:struct<c1:,c2:>>>
' but '<' is found.
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:254)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:88)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:360)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: type expected at the position 0 of '::::array<struct<a:string.b:array,c:struct<c1:,c2:>>>
' but '<' is found.
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.expect(TypeInfoUtils.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.expect(TypeInfoUtils.java:358)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.parseType(TypeInfoUtils.java:419)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils$TypeInfoParser.parseTypeInfos(TypeInfoUtils.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(TypeInfoUtils.java:817)
at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.initialize(JsonSerDe.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.AbstractSerDe.initialize(AbstractSerDe.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:533)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:440)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.checkValidity(Table.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.alterTable(DDLTask.java:3581)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:252)
... 11 more

Please suggest what is going wrong. Thanks!